# Windows Vista users verification

Tags: c#, windows, validation, windows-vista

I want to verify that a given username/password pair is a valid Windows Vista account using c#.

Answer (score 2):

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

// validate the credentials
bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword")
```

Easy peasy

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PInvoke to [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) or, alternatively, use System.Diagnostics.Process to start a new process with a specified username/password and see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the System.Security namespace could help you